# Java cleared collection not freeing up heap

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, set

I am currently developing a game and choose Java as my main development platform. I kind of regret this now since I have encountered a major memory leak which I do not fully understand. I am by far not new to Java, but for some reason, I just can't wrap my head around this error. The basic problem is that I load my gameworld in pieces in order not to use too much memory. After the player leaves an area, set area which is saved within a map, gets removed from the map. For some reason, the garbage collector does not delete the area after that and the amount of ram spend just keeps increasing until I stop the game. From my understanding of the garbage collector, it should delete heap variables when there is no thread accessing the object any longer which is the case in my game.

Because my game engine is already pretty big and too complex to experiment with, I made a small test program to check whether my understanding of the garbage collector is "garbage ;P" or not. (I know I am punny, right?... sry ^^)

Here is the program:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {

new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>();

        System.out.println("Saving stuff");
        for (long i = 0; i < 19999999L; i++) {
            set.add(i);
        }

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        System.out.println("Clearing stuff");
        set.clear();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();

    Thread.sleep(40000);
    System.out.println("Exiting program!");
}
```

As you can see, I am basicaly just saving a bunch of longs in a HashSet and clearing it afterwards. To make sure, that the longs would not be accessed any longer, the thread which they belong to even stops. But for some ood reason no memory frees up.

During my carrer as a programmer I have never been this confused about an issue like I am right now. I hope I can resolv this without rewriting everything in C++, which would realy suck since the program has gotten insainly big over the months I have worked on it so far.

I am happy for any help you guys can provide and I realy hope I can solve this one,
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The thing about toy programs like this is a) they don't necessarily exercise what you want to show (there's nothing in here to trigger a GC, not that you can anyway); b) they don't necessarily bear a relationship to the behavior of your actual code, so they're not actually illustrative of the actual problem.

Comment: From my understanding of the garbage collector it should delete heap variables -> I think this sentence is wrong, specifically SHOULD , there is nothing GC SHOULD do, you can only assume GC MAY do something. GC behavior, semantics are undetermined and there is no control over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not expect a Java application to release memory back to the OS following a garbage collection.

The normal behavior of a JVM is to keep the heap size large so that it doesn't need to run the GC often.  It is "eager" to request more memory from the OS, and "reluctant" to give it back.

(But if the JVM does decide that the heap is too big, it will give some memory back.  Eventually.  I think you need at least 2 full GC cycles before this happens ...)

But here's the thing.  If you did the same thing in C++, there is a good chance that the normal C++ allocator would not give back memory to the OS either.  Certainly it wouldn't *be able to* do that if the creation and destruction of the big data structure resulted in fragmentation of the C++ heap.

Comment: So as long as I do not encounter an OutOfMemoryException I am fine? Seems a little fishy to me

Comment: As long as you do not have a memory leak, or use too much memory, you are fine.  (More or less.  There can be other 2nd-order performance considerations.)

Comment: If you are concerned about memory usage patterns, investigate them using VisualVM or some other memory profiler.  Or by turning on the JVM's GC logging.  VisualVM is also helpful for tracking down memory leaks in your application if you suspect you have one.

Answer (score 0):

A recent 3D application of mine is having a progressively larger memory over time as well.

The reason I found out is not the geometry / texture is not being collected by the garbage collector. Instead, when I try to instantiate a new geometry, the library I use also created an `event listener`on the geometry, since the event listener is at a global scope, it is never being collected.

I manually detached the event listener and the collector does it's job correctly.

Hope it would help

Comment: Also, `System.gc();` and  `Runtime.gc();` would suggest the garbage collection if you really want to test something out

Comment: I currently do not have dynamic meshes so there is no need for them to leave their scope after they get pushed to the GPU :) So no geometry in my heap ^^ But thanks anyway